# Adding Searchbar with leaflet-geosearch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, maps, react-leaflet

I'm trying to add a search bar using `leaflet-geosearch` to my Leaflet Map in React (`react-leaflet`)

```
import { Map, TileLayer, MapControl } from 'react-leaflet'
import { GeoSearchControl, OpenStreetMapProvider } from 'leaflet-geosearch'

class Search extends MapControl {
  createLeafletElement() {
    return GeoSearchControl({
      provider: new OpenStreetMapProvider(),
      style: 'bar'
    })
  }
}

...

export class MapContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Map
          ref={m => { this.leafletMap = m; }}
          center={this.state.position}
          zoom={this.state.zoom}
        >
          <TileLayer
            attribution={tilesAttr}
            url={tilesUrl}
          />
          <Search />
        </Map>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

When I run this I get a TypeError:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
>   Search.componentDidMount
>
> ```
> };
>
> MapControl.prototype.componentDidMount = function componentDidMount() {
> -> this.leafletElement.addTo(this.props.leaflet.map);
> };
>
> MapControl.prototype.componentDidUpdate = function componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
> ```

Has anyone had success adding a search bar to their leaflet map?

Answer (score 1):

```
const GeoSearch = withLeaflet(Search)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The list of changes:

- wrap your component with `withLeaflet` HOC to ensure the control is getting initialized once the map is loaded, for example `export default withLeaflet(GeoSearch);`
- control needs to be added into map explicitly, for
  example in `componentDidMount` function
- `leaflet-geosearch` css needs to be referenced, for example via `public/index.html`

Example

```
class Search extends MapControl {

  createLeafletElement(opts) {
    const provider = new OpenStreetMapProvider();
    const searchControl = new GeoSearchControl({
      provider: provider,
      //position: "topleft",
      style: "bar"
    });

    return searchControl;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { map } = this.props.leaflet;
    map.addControl(this.leafletElement);
  }
}
```

Here is [a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-uxcvji)

Answer (score 1):

Use "withLeaflet"

answer here
https://github.com/smeijer/leaflet-geosearch/issues/167#issuecomment-403107336

and here
https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/custom-components.html

```
*import ...unrelated imports*
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, MapControl, Popup, ZoomControl, withLeaflet } from 'react-leaflet';
import { GeoSearchControl, OpenStreetMapProvider } from 'leaflet-geosearch';

class SearchMap extends MapControl {

    createLeafletElement() {
      return GeoSearchControl({
        provider: new OpenStreetMapProvider(),
        style: 'bar',
        showMarker: true,
        showPopup: false,
        autoClose: true,
        retainZoomLevel: false,
        animateZoom: true,
        keepResult: false,
        searchLabel: 'search'
      });
    }
}


class MapContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const SearchBar = withLeaflet(SearchMap);  {/*  this part is needed */}
    return(
      <Map>
        <SearchBar />
        {/* rest of your map elements */}
      </Map>
    );
  }
}

export default MapContainer;
```